# Amazon Presigned URL - Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, request, pre-signed-url

I have been assigning a pre-assigned URL. When I try to get the url by using python's own library 'requests' it shows me this message.

```
"response"=>["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>W9AYDBXYWC3SC3", "9F</RequestId><HostId>RzP63sVii2NOCFRNlPyP4/Iz/7sMn8rXJanhNfB8gnQmrDJmCQYk1igJ7TmcBpPubFH4I5QAAo4=</HostId></Error>"]}
```

But the thing is when I try to hit with the postman. It works well. I don't know the actual reason behind it. Will appreciate your response on it.
Here's how I'm accessing the url

```
import requests
file_response = requests.get(data.get('file_path'), stream=True)
```

Comment: can you elaborate what `data.get('file_path')` is and how you are actually created the signed url?